# Custom AndroidJUnitRunner dependencies injection

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have a custom implementation of `AndroidJUnitRunner` (let's call it `MyRunner`) and will need to access my dagger graph from it.

Actually, I need some of the injected components to register an IdlingResource. Is there any proper way of passing those components/dependencies to a custom `AndroidJUnitRunner` ?

Either through constructor or by seeking it from the inside of MyRunner.

Note: the custom runner is used in test classes as a class reference in an annotation:
`@RunWith(MyRunner::class)` so using a custom constructor is not that obvious.